# Excel dynamic chart scale

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, scale

I am creating an excel dashboard with many charts and i have connected them to slicers. However the problem that I have is the charts' scale seems to be static (i.e. from 0 to 80). 
I am using excel pivot tables so whenever i add a new data point it does get shown on the table also if the value is higher. 
However if you see the data on the chart there is not much data in the range between 0 - 30 but the scale is still fixed starting at 0. 
How can i get the tables to adjust also the minimum range automatically so if the lowest data point is 30 then the scale also start somewhere nearby ?

[image: img1]

Comment: You can always manually change them by right clicking the axis and setting the minimum value - personally I utilize VBA and dynamically set them like so: `ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 30`, etc.

Comment: I want them to adjust automatically if possible to show only the range where there is data?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no built in feature that adjusts the minimum value like that - it will most often default to 0. You'll have to look into adding some VBA like in the examples [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2646-excel-change-chart-axis-min-max-value-with-formula.html).